# Listen to pushed data in Blackberry app without help of BES

Tags: http, blackberry, java-me, push

How can I listen to data pushed by the server using http connection ? I dont want to use BES server.
How this can be achieved?

My Blackberry Os version is 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean pushed in the sense of MDS Push data, the only way to do that is from an MDS server which means either a BES or using RIM's BIS with Web Signals. Otherwise I think you need more specifics.

Comment: I have a server which is ready to push data to Blackberry device.I need a communication way using http to receive this pushed data...Also I dont want to use BES push either...Thanks...

Comment: If you don't want to use BES (or any of its derivatives) then you are left with Web Signals (which requires Blackberry Alliance membership). The other options are polling (not really a good option), or triggered polling. Monitor for incoming SMS on a particular port (requires the knowledge and infrastructure to send SMS, which I can't help you with), or monitor for incoming email of a particular format. This has been used by many people, if the data size is small it can be the payload of the email message.

Comment: We have a server side implementation that pushes data to client. But I am not able to receive it on datainputstream . Server successfully sends data to client,but client is not able to read it. Any help appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Sounds like you are describing an MDS push, for which you need at least the MDS server portion of the BES.

Comment: Hi,at this point of time in my project,I can't afford BES push. Also I had a look over BIS-B push which is also a paid service. Is there any alternative available? I really need to implement this as soon as possible.Please help me....